# Arithmetic operation in C

Tags: c, arithmetic-expressions

I was wondering if something like this is feasible in C programming:

```
I_scaled = (I_Avg * i_scaler) / (TWOPOWER24);
  16b        32b       16b          2^24
```

where:

- `I_scaled` is `int` (16bits)
- `I_Avg` is `long` (32bits)
- `i_scaler` is `int` (16 bits)
- `TWOPOWER24 = 2^24`

I_avg max value =  134217720. 
i_scaler max value =  37780

I ask this because the intermediate operations take more space than an int does, but at the end the result is lower than 16 bits. Is this feasible?

Thank you

Comment: AVR Atmega 8 microchip

Comment: @Joachim: a bunch of microcontrollers still have 16-bit ints.

Comment: Operands will be promoted to type long and that result is then assigned to I_scaled.

Comment: Understood..but is completely correct then, right?

Comment: While `i_scale` will be promoted to `long`, I'm not so sure about the `TWOPOWER24` expression. Can you please show the *exact* definition of `TWOPOWER24`?

Comment: The result is correct, unless `I_Avg * i_scaler` overflows (the result is a 32bits data type)

Comment: It never overflows. Thanks.

Comment: @Aldridge1991: can you post the max range for the `I_Avg` and `i_scaler` variables? If it never overflows, then `I_Avg` should be 16 bit.

Comment: I_avg: 134217720. i_scaler: 37780

Comment: @Aldridge1991: `134217720` is well over 16-bits, this will suerly overflow.

Comment: but don't forget the division by 2^24

Comment: the max result `5070745461600` is too large for 32bit. Also the `37780` won't fit in an 16bit int

Comment: @Aldridge1991: the result of multiplying `134217720` and `37780` (I am presuming that's an `unsigned int`?) is `0x049C9FFB6360`. This will get truncated to `0x9FFB6360` before division.

Comment: That solves my initial question then...

Answer (score 4):

To store the intermediate result of multiplying a 16-bit number with a 32-bit one, you need a type which is capable of storing 48 bits. In your example, compiler would first promote both operands to 32-bit values (`long` on your architecture), and the result would also be truncated to 32 bits before dividing, so you wouldn't get the correct answer.

The simplest approach might be to simply cast one of the operands to a `long long`, although you need to check if your compiler is willing to efficiently translate this to 32-bit arithmetic:

```
I_scaled = ((long long)I_Avg * i_scaler) >> 24;
```

Comment: You first sentence doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @this: 48-bits? Why not?

Comment: First of all you are multiplying a long with a long as the promotions are performed. The result of that multiplication is a long. There is no intermediate step. And that result is certainly not stored in some 48bits(?). The result might overflow but it is  32 bit( assuming long is 32bit )

Comment: @this: yes, the result will be truncated to 32 bits, but the result of the arithmetic operation will be a 48 bit number in the worst case. Of course it's not stored in 48 bits, I wrote that you need 48 bits to store the correct result.

Comment: No, the result will never be a 48 bit number, it will only overflow if it exceeds the size for a long.

Comment: @this: I still don't understand your reasoning. Of course it will overflow, that's what I wrote. 1) you **need** 48 bits. 2) you **have** 32 bits. 3) you **must** cast to 64 bits.

Comment: You answer reads as the result is a 48 bit number. You might want to make if clearer if you wish.

Comment: @this: the reason why I wrote this is that in these resource-limited architectures you really want to keep track of the resolution of your variables. If OP is utilizing only 48 bits of a 64 bit variable, he is (theoreticaly) losing 16-bits of precision. In this case, the `i_scaler` constant could easily be a 32-bit number and provide better resolution. Equally, if the result of multiplying maximum values of these two operands would fit into (say) 34-bits, then it would potentially make sense to handle scaling differently and avoid using (potentially expensive) 64-bit operations.